# Value Injecter : Dto to Domain Model (NHibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, dto, automapping, valueinjecter

I am using [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to map properties from a Domain model to a DTO served up via a Service Layer. The service in question also accepts updates... so an updated DTO is passed in and this is then injected to the domain object and saved.

```
    // Domain
    public class Member 
    {
      public Country Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country 
    {
      public string Code { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    //Dto
    public class MemberDto 
    {
       public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    //Transformation Method attempt 1
    public Member InjectFromDto (MemberDto dto, Member source)
    {
       source = source.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(dto);
       return source;
    }
```

Now all this above code does is updates the Property Member.Country.Code which is obviously not what I need it to do.

So from the docs, I figured I needed to create an override and got this:

```
public class CountryLookup: UnflatLoopValueInjection<string, Country>
    {
        protected override Country SetValue(string sourcePropertyValue)
        {
            return countryService.LookupCode(sourcePropertyValue);
        }
    }


 //revised transformation call
 //Transformation Method attempt 2
    public Member InjectFromDto (MemberDto dto, Member source)
    {
       source = source.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(dto)
                      .InjectFrom<CountryLookup>(dto);
       return source;
    }
```

**My problem is during debugging, CountryLookup never gets called.**

Possible reasons I can think of:

- Nhibernate Proxy classes causing value injecter to not match the Country type? Tho this doesnt make sense because it works during the flattening.
- Perhaps the unflattening isn't firing for some reason. I.e Dto is CountryCode and Domain is Country.Code

**I need to use the CountryCode property on the Dto to call a countryService.LookupCode to return the correct object to use during the update injection.**

Comment: tell us what are you trying to achieve, the first attempt works, but it's not what you need, what do you need ?

Comment: your injection named CountryLookup will unflat from string to Country which means it looks to get value from CountryCode of type string and put it into Country.Code of type Country

Comment: @Omu thats correct so for example if my Country object is Country: { Code: USA, Name: United States} and my Dto passes in CountryCode: "CA" it just sets the Country.Code property to CA and leaves the 'Name' property as United States. Remember I am updating a pre-populated domain object... Because of this i need to call my countryService to lookup the correct Country object. I want to capture the 'Code' from the Dto, and then use that code to lookup the correct Country object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the suggestion/reference from Omu this was the specific code to the problem.

```
 public class CountryLookup : ExactValueInjection
    {
        private ICountryService countryservice;

        public CountryLookup(ICountryService countryService)
        {
           this.countryService = countryService; 
        }

        protected override bool TypesMatch(Type s, Type t)
        {
            return (s == typeof(string)) && (t == typeof (Country));

        }
        protected override Object SetValue(object v)
        {
            if (v == null) 
                return null;

            var country = countryService.LookupCode((string) v);
            return country;
        }

        public override string SourceName()
        {
            return "CountryCode";
        }

        public override string TargetName()
        {
            return "Country";
        }    
    }

public Member InjectFromDto (MemberDto dto, Member source)
{
   source = source.InjectFrom<UnflatLoopValueInjection>(dto)
                  .InjectFrom<CountryLookup>(dto);
   return source;
}
```

Comment: yes, this should work (although I don't see where you set the constructor parameter ICountryService), I just wanted you to look at a more generic way, an injection for everything

Comment: The constructor parameter is set in this case through Castle Windsor dependency injection. It's a bit of a mute point for the solution tho as the actual look up service call isn't that relevant.

Comment: Also, i will be considering a generic solution for this project using your suggestions, thankyou :)

Answer (score 3):

unflattening would be to do this:

```
entity.Country.Code <- dto.CountryCode
```

what you need is:

```
entity.Country <- dto.CountryCode
```

so the solution for you would be to inherit an ExactValueInjection where you would go from CountryCode to Country.

what **I recommend you to do** is do the same that I did in the live demo of another project of mine http://awesome.codeplex.com

where I have something like this:

```
    public class Entity
    {
       public int Id{get;set;}
    }
    public class Member : Entity
    {
        public Country Country{get;set;}
    }
    public class MemberDto : DtoWithId
    {
        public int? Country {get;set;}
    }
```

and use these injections to go from entity to dto and back

```
    public class NullIntToEntity : LoopValueInjection
        {
            protected override bool TypesMatch(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
            {
                return sourceType == typeof(int?) && targetType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity));
            }

            protected override object SetValue(object sourcePropertyValue)
            {
                if (sourcePropertyValue == null) return null;
                var id = ((int?) sourcePropertyValue).Value;

                dynamic repo = IoC.Resolve(typeof(IRepo<>).MakeGenericType(TargetPropType));

                return repo.Get(id);
            }
        }
//(you also need to have a generic repository, notice IRepo<>)    
    public class EntityToNullInt : LoopValueInjection
        {
            protected override bool TypesMatch(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
            {
                return sourceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Entity)) && targetType == typeof (int?); 
            }

            protected override object SetValue(object o)
            {
                if (o == null) return null;
                return (o as Entity).Id;
            }
        }
```

these injections will handle not just going from int? to **Country** and back but also any other type which inherits **Entity**

Comment: This comment lead to the specific answer to my problem but doesnt show the exact answer, which ill post. Can this be +1'd as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is a framework calling the setter method?  In most DI frameworks, the standard is lowercase 's' in the setMethod().  Just a first-thought recommendation.

Comment: Are you referring to the SetValue method? If so, that is part of the ValueInjecter framework.

Comment: Nick, this is .NET, not Java, .NET standard is pascal case for method names, not camel case.